# Bash: find references to filenames in other files

Tags: bash, grep

**Problem:**
I have a list of filenames, filenames.txt:
Eg.

```
/usr/share/important-library.c
/usr/share/youneedthis-header.h 
/lib/delete/this-at-your-peril.c
```

I need to rename or delete these files and I need to find references to these files in a project directory tree: `/home/noob/my-project/` so I can remove or correct them.

My thought is to use bash to extract the filename: `basename filename`, then grep for it in the project directory using a for loop.

```
FILELISTING=listing.txt
PROJECTDIR=/home/noob/my-project/

for f in $(cat "$FILELISTING"); do
    extension=$(basename ${f##*.})
    filename=$(basename ${f%.*})
    pattern="$filename"\\."$extension"
    grep -r "$pattern" "$PROJECTDIR"
done
```

I could royally screw up this project -- does anyone see a flaw in my logic; better: do you see a more reliable scalable way to do this over a huge directory tree? Let's assume that revision control is off the table ( it is, in fact ).

Comment: You can always make a copy of the project, and impose revision control on the copy.  Git would be largely invisible - a `.git` directory in the top-level directory would suffice.  You should test on a copy of the project (or a copy of a subset of the project).  Avoid going live on the project that you could screw up -- Murphy's Law applies!

Comment: This project involves modifications to the OS and related config files and I'm not sure how to contain all that in an easy to work with repo. I do have smaller aspects in revision control ...but not the OS itself. Which is maybe(?) exceeding the scope of this question.

Comment: If you're modifying the OS, you'd better have your recovery plan in place and tested.  Be very sure that it will all work.  It'll be best to assume that it won't work perfectly -- how will you deal with 2 files that were not modified (when everything else was correctly modified)?  It'll be two files you didn't look at in your trial runs that fail, but they'll be critical ones, as it turns out after the fact.  Of course, using `grep` won't screw anything up (or shouldn't do); it only reads.  It will be when you act on what it reports that you could do the damage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few comments:

- Instead of

  ```
  for f in $(cat "$FILELISTING") ; do
      ...
  done
  ```

  it's somewhat safer to write

  ```
  while IFS= read -r f ; do
      ...
  done < "$FILELISTING"
  ```

  That way, your code will have no problem with spaces, tabs, asterisks, and so on in the filenames (though it still won't support newlines).
- Your goal in separating `f` into `extension` and `filename`, and then reassembling them with `\.`, seems to be that you want the filename to be treated as a literal string; right? Like, you're worried that `grep` will treat the `.` as meaning "any character" rather than as "one dot". A more general solution is to use `grep`'s `-F` option, which tells it to treat the pattern as a fixed string rather than a regex:

  ```
  grep -r -F "$f" "$PROJECTDIR"
  ```
- <s>Your introduction mentions using `basename`, but then you don't actually use it. Is that intentional?</s>
- <s>If your non-use of `basename` is intentional, then `filenames.txt` really just contains a list of patterns to search for; you don't even need to write a loop, in this case, since `grep`'s `-f` option tells it to take a newline-separated list of patterns from a file:</s>

  ```
  grep -r -F -f "$FILELISTING" "$PROJECTDIR"
  ```
- You should back up your project, using something like `tar -czf backup.tar.gz "$PROJECTDIR"`. "Revision control is off the table" doesn't mean you can't have a rollback strategy!

**Edited to add:**

- To pass all your base-names to `grep` at once, in the hopes that it can do something smarter with them than just looping over them just as though the calls were separate, you can write something like:

  ```
  grep -r -F "$(sed 's#.*/##g' "$FILELISTING")" "$PROJECTDIR"
  ```

  (I used `sed` rather than `while`+`basename` for brevity's sake, but you can an entire loop inside the `"$(...)"` if you prefer.)

Comment: Genius! Just goes to show ...one can never re-read the man pages too often!

Comment: I guess one problem with grep using literal strings is that it assumes absolute paths are used in references, or, that the referencing files are not in the same directory ...etc. I edited my original post and added `basename` for this reason. So it looks like I still need the loop but can use the `-F` option to eliminate the messy looking parameter substitution.

Comment: Would it be better to use xargs in combination with grep where the directories are likely to be very large?

Comment: @Bubnoff: You mean, passing many patterns in a single call to `grep`? I'm not sure -- but if so, `xargs` actually won't help, since it would pass them as separate arguments. I'll edit my answer with code to do that (even though I don't know if it'll help).

Comment: I can't find documentation on the `-r` option to read. Not listed in usage blurp at shell, anyway. Could you explain the `while` bit?

Comment: @Bubnoff: Re: the `-r` option to `read`: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/read.html. Without it, a backslash is treated as an escape character.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for an IDE.

You're right that this is a perilous task, and unless you know the build process and the search directories and the order of the directories, you really can't say what header is with which file.

Let's take something as simple as this:

```
# include "sql.h"
```

You have a file in the project `headers/sql.h`. Is that file needed? Maybe it is. Maybe not. There's also a `/usr/include/sql.h`. Maybe that's the one that's actually used. You can't tell without looking at the `Makefile` and seeing the order of the *include* directories which is which.

Then, there are the libraries that get included and may need their own header files in order to be able to compile. And, once you get to the C preprocessor, you really will have a hard time.

This is a task for an IDE (Integrated Development Environment). An IDE builds the project and tracks file and other resource dependencies. In the Java world, most people use Eclipse, and there is a C/C++ plugin for those developers. However, there are [over 2 dozen listed in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B) and almost all of them are open source. The best one will depend upon your environment.

Comment: Retrofitting an IDE into this project is probably not an option at this point. It involves numerous sub-projects, languages and documentation ...etc. Thank you though! I will consider your advice for future projects.